# rmarkdown: hanging-indent citation

Tags: r-markdown, biblatex, csl

The rmarkdown package uses the biblatex with the chicago author-date style as default.

I would like to use hanging-indent in the references, like it the biblatex-chicago package.

[This suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pandoc-discuss/SUZ08-Kc6Og/RapfJ94kpN0J) by David Sanson of using this:

```
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
```

Comes very close, but unfortunately it also indents the first line of the first reference, which does not look very good. Any idea's on how to make this work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simply add the \noindent command.

```
# Bibliography
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
\setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
\noindent
```