# How to generate a hanging citation for an html document in rmarkdown?

Tags: html, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am trying to format a references section for an html printout created in Rmarkdown, and generate a hanging indent for the references to make them easier to read. The text is in just generic text format and is not in `bibtex` or any special reference manager format for Rmarkdown.

I tried the answer given in this question ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691391/rmarkdown-hanging-indent-citation\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691391/rmarkdown-hanging-indent-citation%5C)), however it did not work. I tried several different methods of formatting the text in Latex but they did not work. Below is .Rmd code that shows some of my attempts in a replicable format.

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output:
      html_document: default
    ---
    
    \begin
    \setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
    Author1a, Author2a. Year. A very long title of a journal article that wraps around 1. Journal1. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1b, Author2b. Year. Title2. Journal2. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1c, Author2c. Year. Title3. Journal3. Volume:Pages.\\
    \end
    
    $\setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
    Author1a, Author2a. Year. A very long title of a journal article that wraps around 1. Journal1. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1b, Author2b. Year. Title2. Journal2. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1c, Author2c. Year. Title3. Journal3. Volume:Pages.\\$
    
    $$
    \setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}\\
    Author1a, Author2a. Year. A very long title of a journal article that wraps around 1. Journal1. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1b, Author2b. Year. Title2. Journal2. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1c, Author2c. Year. Title3. Journal3. Volume:Pages.\\
    $$

    ```{=Latex}
    \setlength{\parindent}{-0.2in}
    \setlength{\leftskip}{0.2in}
    \setlength{\parskip}{8pt}
    Author1a, Author2a. Year. A very long title of a journal article that wraps around 1. Journal1. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1b, Author2b. Year. Title2. Journal2. Volume:Pages.\\
    Author1c, Author2c. Year. Title3. Journal3. Volume:Pages.\\
    ```
````

The last chunk is supposed to be a code block defined as a LaTeX environment following https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/raw-latex.html but if I try to include two sets of code blocks to represent the chunk as displayed in Rmarkdown the formatting gets messed up.

I did some more research and it looks like many of the functions of Latex may not be available when knitting to an .html document, only a .pdf or a word document (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1829), and only Latex Math is compatible with html. Thus, the previous question might only be applicable when knitting to a PDF. I don't need to write the references using LaTeX, though it seemed before this to be the easiest way to do so.

Is there a way to format a hanging indent in non-coding text in Rmarkdown when the document to be created is an .html file, rather than a .pdf report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an `html_document` output:

You could set this within script tags within the RMD (not in a chunk or in a chunk-- your choice). You can just write it when you use it, as well.

**None of this is within a code chunk**; this is a text section between chunks.

```
<div style="text-indent: -40px; padding-left: 40px;">

Names. (dates). Titles titles titles titles. *Sources sources sources, number*(number), pages-pages. And of course the DOI with no period

Names. (dates). Titles titles titles titles. *Sources sources sources, number*(number), pages-pages. And of course the DOI with no period

Names. (dates). Titles titles titles titles. *Sources sources sources, number*(number), pages-pages. And of course the DOI with no period

</div>
```

This is what this output looks like:

[image]

I don't know what your knowledge level is, so if this is something you're familiar with, just ignore it. The `div` tags and inline styles work with regular text when rendering as `HTML`.

For every opening tag, you need a closing tag. `<div> and </div>`

The asterisks cause the text to be italicized.

This could be useful: 96 px is about 1 inch. (Should the amount of indent be critical.)